# How do I avoid white space from being saved into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a table named `LOGIN`:

```
Userid  password 
 user1   pwd1
 user2   pwd2
```

So my concern is, when entering Userid, it does not check if white space is there.

For example, I'd like it to show an error when `us er 1` is the Userid.

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem? It can also be viewed as expected behaviour. But if you must make it acceptable, then you need to remove all white space from the username before you store it, and also before you search for it... How to do that really depends on the programming language you're working with, but it should be very simple.

Comment: IS it a good idea to remove spaces from usernames and/or passwords without informing the user that this is being done? Perhaps it is better to say that their username/password is invalid and telling them what is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [LTRIM/RTRIM](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/24/sql-server-trim-function-udf-trim/) function and [`REPLACE(string,' ','')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx). This might become very intensive. I would however strongly suggest to have a form of validation and check the integrity of your data before it is entered into the database.

Comment: i agree that `REPLACE()` should be used. LTRIM/RTRIM won't be able to remove spaces in between as seen in the example `us er 1` by the user. Also, I second @JLC007 in validation check before saving into the database.

Comment: The LTRIM/RTRIM is just for precaution. If spaces appear in between text then chances are good that it might appear in front or at the back of the string. Thanks @rationalboss!